# Increment id for new block

Tags: angular, increment

pls  help
1. Need to add unic id to new element
2. if add console.log(...), it will be work correctly, but otherwise it always stay id: 3 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVDh1.png) 
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlh8U.png) 
 `onAdd() {
    if(this.carModel === '' || this.carName === '') return
      this.id = this.id++;`
 -work

`onAdd() {
    if(this.carModel === '' || this.carName === '') 
return this.id = this.id++;`
 -don`t work

Comment: Try

    return this.id++;

This should be enough in your case

Comment: Can you post a simple code example of what you currently have, and what you are trying to do? It will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I just edit, but why it so depends where is "return"?

Answer (score -1):

I just remove "return" on top and then write in new line this.id...

[image: solution]